# Handling shared variables in Spring Boot controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am writing an API in Spring Boot and have a controller that has a BlockingQueue that is going to be shared between incoming requests. Couple questions:

1. Because controllers in Spring Boot are singleton by default, I don't need to make the queue static, correct? (because there would only be one instance of the class and therefore only one blocking queue that all threads will be enqueuing and dequeuing from?).
2. I have an endpoint to add entries to the queue and another endpoint to poll if the added entry was dequeued from the queue and processed. I want to have a separate method (not corresponding to an endpoint) that checks the queue intermittently, dequeues entries and processes them. Would a @Scheduled method do the trick or are there any other concurrency gotchas I am missing?

Comment: With regards to #1, be sure to document that well as it will not scale horizontally.

Comment: Do you say that because the controller is singleton? Not sure I understand how scalability is linked to that. Wouldn't any new machine you add increase the number of threads (aka number of concurrent requests) you can support?

Comment: Yes, but it sounds like you have some logic that relies on queueing. If you use an in-memory solution such as `BlockingQueue` you'll have one controller per server/instance and they'll each have their own queue. Additionally your system won't be resillient to crashes.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the controller can only be singleton for a single machine? That is, if we scale horizontally, each machine hosts its own singleton controller and although threads on the same machine share the same BlockingQueue, those on different machines don't?

Comment: There are libraries to facilitate actual distributed computing, but the overhead/effort isn't always worth it for webapp containers that can more easily be load balanced w/ multiple instances instead.

Comment: I see but was what I understood from your previous answer correct?

Comment: sorry, yes it is.